# Drag and drop images on canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp

I have drag and drop the images on canvas. I have fix the boundaries so that my images not drag out of canvas,but when I zoom-in and zoom-out the images then its boundaries changes,and it would not drag over whole canvas.I have try this till now.

```
         public void Btnedit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
        var button = sender as Button;
        button.IsEnabled = false;
        CompositeTransform CT = new CompositeTransform();
        ImgeracOpen.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
        //ImgeracOpen.ManipulationDelta += Drag_ManipulationDelta;
        ImgeracOpen.ManipulationDelta += Composite_ManipulationDelta;
        ImgeracOpen.RenderTransform = CT;
    }

   void Composite_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // scale the image

        FrameworkElement Elem = sender as FrameworkElement;
        CompositeTransform CT = Elem.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
        if (CT != null)
        {
            CT.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
            CT.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
            CT.CenterX = Elem.ActualWidth / 2;
            CT.CenterY = Elem.ActualHeight / 2;
            if (CT.ScaleX < 0.25) CT.ScaleX = 0.25;
            if (CT.ScaleY < 0.25) CT.ScaleY = 0.25;
            if (CT.ScaleX > 1.15) CT.ScaleX = 1.15;
            if (CT.ScaleY > 1.15) CT.ScaleY = 1.15;

        }

        double Left = Canvas.GetLeft(Elem);
        double Top = Canvas.GetTop(Elem);
        Left += e.Delta.Translation.X;//Get x cordinate 
        Top += e.Delta.Translation.Y;//Get y cordinate 
        //check for bounds 
        if (Left < 0)
        {
            Left = 0;
        }
        else if (Left > (my_canvas.ActualWidth - Elem.ActualWidth))
        {
            Left = my_canvas.ActualWidth - Elem.ActualWidth;
        }

        if (Top < 0)
        {
            Top = 0;
        }
        else if (Top > (my_canvas.ActualHeight - Elem.ActualHeight))
        {
            Top = my_canvas.ActualHeight - Elem.ActualHeight;
        }

        Canvas.SetLeft(Elem, Left);
        Canvas.SetTop(Elem, Top);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I zoom-in and zoom-out the images then its boundaries changes,and it would not drag over whole canvas.

It's because when you scale the Image, the Image's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` won't change and so is `Left` and `Top` that you get from `Canvas.GetLeft` and `Canvas.GetTop`.

To fix the problem, you need to calucate the `Left` and `Top` values when the image scales like below:

[image]

As you can see in the picture. When image scales, the `Left` Value should be `Canvas.Width`-`Image.ActualWidth`-`xOffset` when image hit the right boundary. And when it hit the left boundary `Left` should be equal to `xOffset`.

Through this logic, the codes in `Composite_ManipulationDelta` should be modified like below:

```
void Composite_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // scale the image
    FrameworkElement Elem = sender as FrameworkElement;
    CompositeTransform CT = Elem.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    if (CT != null)
    {
        CT.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        CT.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
        CT.CenterX = Elem.ActualWidth / 2;
        CT.CenterY = Elem.ActualHeight / 2;
        //if (CT.ScaleX < 0.25) CT.ScaleX = 0.25;
        //if (CT.ScaleY < 0.25) CT.ScaleY = 0.25;
        //if (CT.ScaleX > 1.15) CT.ScaleX = 1.15;
        //if (CT.ScaleY > 1.15) CT.ScaleY = 1.15;
    }
    double Left = Canvas.GetLeft(Elem);
    double Top = Canvas.GetTop(Elem);

    //output.Text = "Left:=" + Left + "  Top:=" + Top+"\nActualWidth:="+Elem.Width+"  ActualHeight"+Elem.Height;
    Left += e.Delta.Translation.X;//Get x cordinate 
    Top += e.Delta.Translation.Y;//Get y cordinate 
                                     //check for bounds
    double xOffset = Elem.ActualWidth * (CT.ScaleX-1) / 2;
    double yOffset = Elem.ActualHeight * (CT.ScaleY-1) / 2; 
    if (Left-xOffset < 0)
    {
        Left = xOffset;
    }
    else if (Left > (my_canvas.ActualWidth - Elem.ActualWidth-xOffset))
    {
        Left = my_canvas.ActualWidth - Elem.ActualWidth-xOffset;
    }

    if (Top -yOffset<0 )
    {
        Top = yOffset;
    }
    else if (Top > (my_canvas.ActualHeight - Elem.ActualHeight-yOffset))
    {
        Top = my_canvas.ActualHeight - Elem.ActualHeight-yOffset;
    }

    Canvas.SetLeft(Elem, Left);
    Canvas.SetTop(Elem, Top);
}
```